# How to make a simple data storage which can be used both an app and its service in Android?

Tags: android, service, push-notification, sharedpreferences

I have an Android application and its notification service working  regardless of the app. Both work perfectly. Through a user-defined period of time the service accesses the server to check for new data. If there was a new post, the service notifies the user via notification Pending Intent, through which the user can open and read fresh news. Unread notifications are not accumulated and overwrite  each other, that is user will always see the latest news published.

All this works fine, but users say that alerts are duplicated - are informed of already read news, if there's no new ones. I keep last read news ID in SharedPreferences.

```
if (post.id != PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(service).getLong(
        service.getString(R.string.notifications_last_id), 0)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(service, PostActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(service.getString(R.string.pref_item_id), post.id);
    intent.putExtra(service.getString(R.string.notifications_referrer), true);
    service.sendNotification(post.rubric.title, post.title, R.id.notifications_news_id, PostActivity.class, intent);
    Preferences.setNotificationNewsId(service, post.id);
    Log.d(TAG, service.getString(R.string.notifications_last_id) + ":" + post.id);
}

public static void setNotificationNewsId(Context context, long id) {
    try {
        final SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sp.edit().putLong(context.getString(R.string.notifications_last_id), id).commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In what could be the reason for the duplication of notifications? Or is there an alternative way of storing the last identifier available for the application and for the service?

Comment: ur getting new post id from server?

Comment: @Wiz25 Yes. And compare it with notifications_last_id value in SharedPreferences (0 by default)

Comment: your code looks fine, please debug the code and check..

Comment: `post.id` is string or integer?

Comment: @Wiz25 long integer type

Comment: I tried to check notifications_last_id from application main activity and it show last saved post id so it was saved properly

Comment: Save the value of `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(service).getLong(
        service.getString(R.string.notifications_last_id), 0)` in some variable and use that variable in condition. i don't know weather it works or not just try it